# Maven Throwing error in opening zip file?

Tags: eclipse, maven, archiva

I have added plenty of jar files in My Local **Apache Archiva** and added the **Repository** location and **Dependencies** in my project pom.xml .

```
mvn clean
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

working fine but when i am trying to run

```
mvn install
```

then i am getting exception

```
Error in opening zip files
```

while all jar file downloaded from archiva

Someone suggested delete the .m2 repository and run command again i tried that also but still not able to get resolution.
Note:- I have no any test code in my project
Thanks

Comment: The reason might be that one of the dependencies might not have downloaded correctly (hence deleting the .m2 repo might fix it). If that does not solve the problem you have to go through the dependencies included in you project and see if you are able to unzip them all. If one of them is corrupted download and install the file locally to fix the problem

Comment: Thanks Shyam but i have lots of jar added in Archiva So do you know how can i figure out which jar have issue

Comment: Well, use copy-dependencies to copy them to one folder and check every one (using an ant task perhaps...or shell)

Comment: Actually i just looked my .m2 directory and here all jar files are only 3KB while same jar are showing there actual size in Apache Archiva Directory.

Answer (score 3):

You have corrupt files in your local maven repository. They need to be redownloaded - possibly just deleting the .m2 folder and retrying will fix the issue, if not, you need to find out why your archiva repository is serving you bad files.

You should be able to run `mvn -X install` to find out more detailed information as to which file was failing.

Comment: Thanks as i look on the my .M2 repository and all the jars are only 3kb while same jar showing exact size in Apache Archiva.

Comment: [DEBUG] Searching for sources for org.com:wsdl4j:1.0.0:null at org.com:wsdl4
1.0.0:javadoc
[DEBUG] Searching for sources for org.com:xfe_jdk-14:1.0.0:null at org.com:x
_jdk-14:1.0.0:javadoc
[DEBUG] Searching for sources for org.com:xmlbeans:2.3.0:null at org.com:xml
ans:2.3.0:javadoc
[DEBUG] Searching for sources for org.com:xmlpserver:1.0.0:null at org.com:x
pserver:1.0.0:javadoc
[DEBUG] Searching for sources for org.com:xmlsec:1.4.1:null at org.com:xmlse
1.4.1:javadoc
[DEBUG] Searching for sources for org.com:xpp3:1.0.0:null at org.csdc:xpp3:1.
0:javadoc

Comment: @subodh please add the exception you got as well as couple of lines before that to the question itself

Comment: [INFO] Using Eclipse Workspace: null
[DEBUG] 0 from workspace null
 
[DEBUG] com.com:log4j:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT (selected for null)
[WARNING] Invalid POM for org.com:AMANDA5j2ee:jar:1.0.0, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM C:\Users\sjoshi\.m2\repository\org\com\log4j\1.0.0\log4j-1.0.0.pom: end tag name </head> must be the same as start tag <link> from line 30 (position: TEXT seen

Answer (score 1):

its because of corrupt file in repository delete that specific file which is showing error or delete entire repository and redeploy .

Comment: how is this answer different from the one already given in 2012?